# Sites redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: mac, google-chrome

Not sure if this is the correct place to post this...

So since yesterday, most of the websites that I usually visit are redirecting me to the HTTPS version. Is there a way to revert this back so it goes to https only when there is a proper certificate? The sites I go on do not support that and I always get "Connection not secured" with a crossed off https:

I am on a Mac using Chrome*

Comment: Sounds like you have some malware of some kind installed that's trying to redirect you. Either that or you're on a managed Wifi network that needs you to login.

Comment: Sorry I figured it out. It is Chrome 44